# Конструкции с союзом "ли... или"

Tags: запятые, союзы, однородные-члены, сложное-предложение, или

1. *Видит **ли** он это, **или** не видит* (Г.). (http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=73)

Почему здесь стоит запятая? «Ли… или» соединяют однородные члены предложения и не образуют повторяющего союза, поэтому запятая не ставится согласно "Грамоте" (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392). Однако на "Грамоте" все однородные члены почему-то второстепенные:

*Чувствительные дамы ахали от ужаса; мужчины бились об заклад, кого родит графиня: белого ли или черного ребенка* (А. Пушкин, Арап Петра Великого).

*От света **ли** электричества **или** от волнения она слегка порозовела и кажется моложе* (Л. Андреев, Христиане).

Может, на однородные сказуемые это не распространяется?

Ещё пару моих примеров:

2. *Поднимается **ли** у тебя настроение при общении с ним **или** опускается?*

Аналогично — однородные члены.

3. *Прибавляется **ли** у тебя энергии и энтузиазма, **или** убавляется?*

А вот здесь сложносочинённое предложение с безличными частями, «ли/ль… или» в данном случае рассматриваются как повторяющийся союз и запятая ставится, несмотря на то что предложение вопросительное (согласно той же "Грамоте").

Answer (score 2):

1) **Что важно знать о конструкциях с союзом ЛИ...ИЛИ?**

Надо отличать союз ИЛИ от союза ЛИ...ИЛИ, правила для них немного разные.

Для союза ***ЛИ...ИЛИ*** постановка запятой зависит от статуса союза: одиночный или повторяющийся.  В случае однородных членов это одиночный союз, запятая не ставится. Если это ССП, то запятая ставится. Поэтому сначала решается этот вопрос.

В то же время очевидно, что грамматически однородные односоставные предложения можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым и запятую не ставить  (что также видно по интонации), например у Розенталя: **Приеду** по весне к вам либо **отправлюсь** на Кавказ (Бат).

Для одиночных союзов ***И, ИЛИ*** немного другие правила. Запятая не ставится не только между  однородными членами, но и в ССП при наличии общего элемента, в СПП в случае однородных придаточных.

**Дополнение (о семантике союзов)**

**Обычно правила ориентированы на формальные признаки, но интересно сравнить варианты с точки зрения смысла.** В толковом словаре указано, что слово ЛИ может быть **частицей** с усилительным значением и выражение вопроса, удивления, сомнения, неуверенности. Такую частицу можно изъять из предложения, и тогда мы получим союз ИЛИ для однородных членов. В то же время частица ЛИ может являться частью составного союза ЛИ...ИЛИ (варианта союза ИЛИ...ИЛИ), и этот случай подходит   для сложного предложения.

**Другой интересный аспект проблемы: как одиночный разделительный союз ИЛИ может "соединять" однородные члены в одну фразу,** так что мы не делаем паузу и не ставим запятую (для соединительного союза И это понятно)? Вероятно, этому способствует то общее главное слово, к которому относятся однородные члены. Тогда становится ясно, почему статус союза разный для однородных членов и сложного предложения.

Также желательно помнить, что во всех случаях мы имеем **интонационную подсказку:** то, что явно читается одной фразой, не стоит разделять запятой.

2) **Разбор предложений**

**Видит ли он это или  не видит?** **Видит ли он это, или (он это) не видит?**

Здесь два решения (желательно выбрать первое): если это однородные сказуемые, то запятой нет; если это сложное предложение, то запятая ставится. **Различение делается по общим правилам:** однородные сказуемые тесно связаны по смыслу, имеют сходную грамматическую форму, мало распространены и т.д. Если эти признаки отсутствуют, то это сложное предложение. В школьной практике вопрос  обычно решается в пользу однородных сказуемых, так что вариант с запятой лучше считать авторским.

**Чувствительные дамы ахали от ужаса; мужчины бились об заклад, кого родит графиня: белого ли или черного ребенка.** Это однородные дополнения, поясняют местоимение ***кого***.

**От света ли электричества или от волнения она слегка порозовела и кажется моложе.** Это однородные дополнения.

**Поднимается ли у тебя настроение при общении с ним или опускается?** Выбор в пользу однородных сказуемых.

**Прибавляется ли у тебя энергии и энтузиазма или убавляется?** Грамматически однородные безличные предложения можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым и запятую не ставить.

3) **Правила Розенталя и Лопатина**

**1) Для однородных членов**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100
4. Перед неповторяющимися разделительными союзами или, либо между однородными членами предложения запятая не ставится: Цветы лучше всего собирать утром или под вечер (Пауст.); …**Приеду по весне к вам либо отправлюсь на Кавказ** (Бат.

http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg27.php

§ 27. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами (и, да в знач. «и»; или, либо) не разделяются запятой: Теплоход встал поперек реки и дал течению развернуть его вниз, по ходу (Расп.); День да ночь — сутки прочь (посл.); **Поддержит он Уздечкина или не поддержит?** (Пан.).

**2) В ССП**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Примечания: 1. В сложносочиненном предложении сочетание ли…или рассматривается как повторяющийся союз (в отличие от простого предложения с однородными членами, в котором ли…или не образуют повторяющегося союза, вследствие чего запятая перед или не ставится): **Во сне ль всё это снится мне, или гляжу я в самом деле, на что при этой же луне с тобой живые мы глядели?** (Тютч.); Серьёзно ли в ней гнездилось это намерение, или она только шутки шутила (С.‑Щ.);

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Примечание. Союзы ли... или в сложносочиненном предложении относятся к повторяющимся союзам. Это же сочетание союзов может использоваться и в предложении со сказуемыми, отнесенными к общему подлежащему, тогда запятая перед или не ставится. Ср.: **Судьба ли нас свела опять на Кавказе, или она нарочно сюда приехала, зная, что меня встретит** (Л.). — **Видит ли он это или не видит — не столь важно**.

Comment: "Прибавляется ли у тебя энергии и энтузиазма или убавляется? Грамматически однородные безличные предложения можно приравнять к однородным сказуемым и запятую не ставить". Мне кажется это некой произвольностью. Есть два безличных предложения в составе сложного. Розенталь упоминает только "односоставные безличные предложения, имеющие синонимичные слова" — их здесь нет.

Comment: Хотя у них есть общие дополнения, по сути являющиеся субъектами: энергия и энтузиазм прибавляются или убавляются.

Comment: Хотелось бы получить от вас комментарий.

Comment: И можно ли при наличии паузы перед союзом ИЛИ между однородными членами ставить запятую и считать предложение СПП? «Ноет ли он о своих проблемах, или рассказывает забавные истории?»

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, в справочнике допущена ошибка. Потому что считать в данном случае союз повторяющимся нет никаких оснований. Здесь союз ли ... или соединяет однородные члены, а не части сложного предложения.

Ср. аналогичный пример в справочнике Розенталя.

Видит ли он это или не видит? (Г.)

Союзы ли…или, стоящие при однородных членах предложения, не приравниваются к повторяющимся, поэтому запятая перед или не ставится:

Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.